# Angularjs directive with isolated scope needs clarification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Edit:

There is a functional example in this plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/GFQGP0q3o9RjLAlRANPS?p=preview

Outer scope has $scope.name = 'Donald'

All directives are declared as:

```
<directive-name binding="name">
```

---

This is a multi-part question. Im trying to gain a better understanding of isolated scopes that has a watch or a binding to an outer scope variable.

With a non-isolated scope directive everything works as it should:

```
  // [WORKS]
  .directive('noScopeWithWatch', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, lElement, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.binding, function(name){
          lElement.text('Hello ' + name);
        });
      }
    };
  })
  // returns Hello Donald
```

The confusing part is when I try to isolate the scope and keep the binding. So what Im asking for is a clarification on why some of the following examples work, while and others do not.

If I just add the scope isolation with a 'normal' binding it fails:

```
  // 1. [FAILS]
  .directive('scopeWithWatch', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, lElement, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.binding, function(name){
          lElement.text('Hello ' + name);
        });
      },
      scope: {                                   // new content
        binding: '='                             // new content
      }                                          // new content
    };
  })
  // returns Hello undefined
```

However, using the binding variable in the watch as a string makes it work:

```
  // 2. [WORKS]
  .directive('scopeWithWatchString', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, lElement, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('binding', function(b){     // new content
          lElement.text('Hello ' + b);
        });
      },
      scope: {
        binding: '=' 
      }
    };
  })
  // returns Hello Donald
```

While using the binding variable as an object fails misribly:

```
  // 3. [FAILS]
  .directive('scopeWithWatchObject', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, lElement, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(binding, function(b){       // new content
          lElement.text('Hello ' + b);
        });
      },
      scope: {
        binding: '='
      }
    };
  })
  // Does not work at all
  // Console output - ReferenceError: binding is not defined
```

Trying to reference the binding variable insinde the isolated scope does not work either, but at least does not cause an exception :

```
  // 4. [FAILS]
  .directive('scopeWithWatchScopeObject', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, lElement, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(scope.binding, function(b){  // new content
          lElement.text('Hello ' + b);
        });
      },
      scope: {
        binding: '='
      }
    };
  })
  // returns Hello undefined
```

It turns out that using the binding variable in mustaches in a template works:

```
  // 5. [WORKS]
  .directive('scopeWithTemplate', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: 'Hello {{binding}}',     // new content and linker removed
      scope: {
        binding: '='
      }
    };
  })
  // returns Hello Donald
```

But trying to use them as mustaches in the linker does not.

```
  // 6. [FAILS]
  .directive('scopeWithWatchStringUsingMustashes', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',     
      link: function(scope, lElement, attrs) {        // new content
        scope.$watch('binding', function(){           // new content
          lElement.text('Hello {{binding}}');         // new content  
        });                                           // new content
      },                                              // new content
      scope: {
        binding: '='
      }
    };
  })
  // returns Hello {{binding}}
```

Here is the plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/GFQGP0q3o9RjLAlRANPS?p=preview
(Im currently at version 78, please fork if you want to use it in your answer.)

Could someone please explain to me why some examples work while others do not.

Comment: Can you show how are you declaring directive in html.

Comment: Please check the link at the bottom. It is a fully functional plnkr example with both html and javascript.
I'll move it up in the question just in case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple answer to this, which applies to all the examples here.  The Angular documentation on [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile) explains this, but it is easy to misunderstand.  The entire purpose of an isolated scope is to create a scope that is consumed ONLY by the directive that declares it.  In order to do so, a new variable is created which stores the value as an alias of the parent scope.

There are 3 major definition types:  `@`, `=`, `&`

> @ or @attr - bind a local scope property to the value of DOM attribute. The result is always a string since DOM attributes are strings.
>
> = or =attr - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value of the attr attribute.
>
> & or &attr - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope.

The only difference between `@` and `=` is bi-directional support.  The `=` definition will still return a string result.

So, what you have, in order, is:

1. Isolated scope does not provide access to the attrs collection, it only has access to it's own isolated scope items.  This will not work, as there is no attrs object in the scope.
2. Works as intended, `binding='name'` is matched to `binding: '='` and `'binding'` is accessable as an alias in the isolated scope.
3. Fails, because attrs are always strings, they are not javascript objects.
4. Fails,

> The 'isolate' scope differs from normal scope in that it does not prototypically inherit from the parent scope. This is useful when creating reusable components, which should not accidentally read or modify data in the parent scope.
>
> Works, for the same reason as 2.  The bindings are properly matched.  Templates are handled by `$compile` automatically.
>
> Fails, because the `lElement.text` is simply that, text.  using an expression within a text assignment requires an additional manual compile step before the text is sent to the dom, else the `{{}}` expression is treated as plain text.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer!
I still dont understand one thing though. It has to do with example 4. I understand I cant access scope.name in the directive, but how come I cant access scope.binding? Shouldn't scope: { binding: '=' } add some variable to the directives scope with the alias binding?

Comment: no, scope is a "special" object, they just name it scope to avoid (or create?) confusion.  In a normal controller, the $scope object is created to hold all of the child attributes.  In case of a directive, the directive ITSELF is it's own scope, so when you refer to an aliased attribute, it's really `self.attr`, not `scope` scope is merely used as a keyword to tell angular to alias the attrs

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh..... Ok! Is it stored in some other object then? Or Is it only accessible by referencing the alias as a string?

Comment: the scope object still exists, else you couldn't do things like scope.$watch.  when you add scope: to the directive, you are forcing the directive itself to create it's own variables that are self contained, and have the same lifespan as the directive, and telling angular that anything not 'angular' in the scope object ($ prefixed) the directive can't access.

Comment: Hmm. Let me rephrase my last question. If I declare scope: { binding: '=' }. Is there some object that would let me type $watch(xxx.binding, ...) rather than $watch('binding', ...)?

Comment: no, the isolated scope isn't a normal object, it's a dictionary  (hash object) of key/value pairs, so when you provide the `'binding'` key, you get that value returned from the dictionary.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand better now. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to address these

1. This does not work because $watch method take expression defined on scope. `attrs.binding` has value `"name"`, and there is no `name` property on isolated scope.
2. Works because watch is on `binding` property of scope.
3. This is not allowed. This should be string.
4. This should work. Not sure why is this not working.
5. `binding` is defined on isolated scope and it works
6. Whey you set `lElement.text('Hello {{binding}}');`, it needs to compiled the content for the expressions to be evaluated and hence this expression would not work.

When you say

`<scope-with-watch binding="name"></scope-with-watch>` and do isolated scope, the binding is between `name` property defined on parent scope and the `binding` property on isolated scope.